# Google Maps not working using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Here is my code. I just want a simple map using jQuery. But I don't see the map when I open it on my browser. When I remove this statement:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I can see the map. But I need this script too in the same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map {
        width:700px;
        height:400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gomap-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#map").goMap();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jQuery.noConflict`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/js/jquery.gomap-1.3.2.js"></script> 
    <script>
        var jq = jQuery.noConflict()
             jq(function() { 
                jq("#map").goMap(); 
            });
        </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: which browser you use.?